# Is it okay to contact companies directly and ask about available jobs?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, new-job

I am wondering if it is frowned upon to e-mail companies directly to ask if they have any positions available.  I understand that most businesses these days have a "Careers" section, but they typically also have a career advisor / hiring manager type person listed.

**Is it poor form to reach out to this person directly, listing your major skills or attaching a resume, and asking if they have anything available in that field?**

The company I currently work for hires from within whenever possible before posting to the job sites.

**If someone reaches out from outside the company and is fully qualified would they be considered?**

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know many who done that, also who showed up in the company in person and asked for jobs within a certain field, and got a job.

You don't need to spam emails though, never! Just focus on one company at a time. Contact them with the minimal information possible but the needed and complete one.

For example:

> "Hello,
>   Good day.
>
> This is YourFullNameHere and I heard about your company from
>   YourSourceHere. I was wondering if there are any available vacancies
>   for YourFieldHere positions right now. If yes, could you please guide
>   me on how to apply or/and who to contact?
>
> Thank you"

Note: This works in person as well. And it is better to get in a contact with a manager that you know he is within your field than to get in contact with info desks / receptionists.

Comment: I agree with keeping the initial contact simple.  If they are interested, they'll ask for more info.  Also, it might be more beneficial to start with a phone call.  That way you get an immediate answer instead of having your emails possibly ignored.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you @Sandra K.  I will definitely take this into consideration and follow these steps.  And thank you as well for your input NotME

Comment: In Finland, this is often the "only" way to find a job in some fields. You are expected to show self-initiative and this is apparently considered as a prime example.